# HttpClient POST data to RESTful API data not being read by the server

Tags: android, django, rest, django-rest-framework, androidhttpclient

I tried to do a Http post to a RestFul service (django with Rest Framework). GET method works fine but POST method gives me problems. I think it may be the credential issue or string formatting issue. Here's the Android REST client code.

```
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlString);

        String encoding = Base64
                .encodeToString(new String("username":"password")
                .getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("username", "apple");
        obj.put("pw", "apple");
        obj.put("email", "apple@gmail.com");
        obj.put("name", "apple");

        System.out.println(obj.toString());
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
        entity.setContentType("application/json");

        request.setEntity(entity);
        // Send request to WCF service
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        // Get the status of web service
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        // print status in log
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("Status Line", "Webservice: " + line);
        }
```

Here's the Android aplog:

```
I/System.out﹕ {"email":"apple@gmail.com","username":"apple","name":"apple","pw":"apple"}

D/Status Line﹕ Webservice: {"username": ["This field is required."], "email": ["This field is required."], "pw": ["This field is required."], "name": ["This field is required."]}
```

Here's the log from Django server:

```
[05/Aug/2014 15:09:39] "POST /split/api_post_user/ HTTP/1.1" 400 151
```

I also tried CURL and the following script works fine.

```
curl -u username:password -X POST \
--data '{"username" : "apple" , "pw" : "12345", "email" : "abc@gmail.com", "name" : "John" }' \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
$URL
```

The second line of the logcat is the response from server.
For example, if I use a wrong user/password pair. It will give me

```
[Webservice: {"detail": "Invalid username/password"}].
```

If I omit the setHeader("Authorization") part, it will give me

```
[Webservice: {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}]
```

Comment: That logcat is basically the full logcat. That piece of android code will be running in an Asynctask in the onCreate() of the main activity. I also tried to do a GET method (no username/password needed) on another api and it works fine.

Comment: i could not understand ur log

Comment: hmm...thanks for helping. Sorry for the confusing logcat. I printed two lines. The first line is the JSONObject.toString(). The second line is the response from the Django Rest server.

Comment: yes right response is confusing

Comment: does this api works fine ? tested on broswer ?or any rest client?

Comment: Yup, I tested on browser and CURL.

Comment: can i try with ur url at my end? can u pass me url?

Comment: you can try below code ..or else we can chat to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the code of decoding password.

```
    String encoding = Base64
            .encodeToString(new String("username":"password")
            .getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code ..place below code in ur Activity Class

```
class PlaceOrder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPst = new HttpPost(

                "yout_url");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(

                2);

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "apple"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "apple"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",
                        "apple@gmail.com"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "apple"));

                httpPst.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

                HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpPst);

                String str = convertStreamToString(
                        httpRes.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

                Log.i("mlog", "outfromurl" + str);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;

        }

    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        try {

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

And call`new PlaceOrder().execute();` from ur **onCreate** method

Comment: Thanks. I will try this as soon as i get home and let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: hmmm... it doesn't work. The output: I/mlog﹕ outfromurl{"username": ["This field is required."], "email": ["This field is required."], "pw": ["This field is required."], "name": ["This field is required."]}